# login input fields inline with title

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the login input fields to be on the same line as the h1 title.  However I am struggling with doing this. I've read that you are suppose to float the input fields left but everything seems to be misaligned.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar__title">
        <h1>Power List App</h1>
        <div class="menu-bar__login">
            <form action="">
                <label for="username"></label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <label for="password"></label>
                <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="registration-section">
        <h2>What is a power list?</h2>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        </p>
        <h1>Register Here:</h1>
        <form action="">
            <label for="username-register"></label>
            <input type="text" id="username-register" placeholder="Username"> 
            <br></br>
            <label for="fn-register"></label>
            <input type="text" id="fn-register" placeholder="First Name"> 
            <br></br>
            <label for="email-register"></label>
            <input type="text" id="email-register" placeholder="Email"> 
            <br></br>
            <label for="gender-registration"></label>
            <select name="gender" id="gender-registration">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Gender</option>
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select>
            <br></br>
            <label for="password-register"></label>
            <input type="text" id="password-register" placeholder="Password">
            <br></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <footer>
        <a href="">Created by: Cerdafied Development</a></p>
        <p>Follow Me On:</p>
        <p>Instagram</p>
        <p>Yo</p>
    </footer>
</body>



**_menu-bar.css**
.menu-bar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    &__title {
        font-weight: 300;
        color: $mainRed;
        float: left;
    }
    
    &__login {
        float: right;
    }
    @mixin clearfix;
}
```

[image]

An explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

I need the Power List app heading inline with the login inputs so I can add a border bottom to it.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be great if you could show the compiled CSS instead of whichever preprocessor you're using.

Comment: You could put the h1 tag inside your form tag and add css to h1 as display: inline;

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can help position your title and form fields in the same line. You can add the following css to your `.menu-bar` class:

```
.menu-bar{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
```